# Running Appium test on real device - android

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium

I need to perform an Appium POC and I was wonder if it possible to execute an Appium test on real connected device instead of emulator android emulator

10x

Comment: You might be interested to read [the official documentation](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-on-real-ios-devices) for testing Appium on real iOS and Android device.

Comment: Thanks, but I see that the description is only for connecting a real IOS device but no Android

Comment: Below the long description for iOS, there is a short paragraph for Android.

Comment: ye , saw it :) tried every thing , but it doesn't work. once I'm trying to launche the server which deploy my app on nexsus 5 it crashes ...

Comment: Perhaps you can edit this question to include that information to focus to a specific issue. As of current, this question seems too broad.

Comment: What does "10x" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kate**: These are my settings, hope it helps.

- My appium version screenshot above: **1.3.4**
- My general settings screenshot

[image]

- Android settings
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to show test on any attached device (if possible) coz simulator takes much time to load thus may fail your test if not handled properly.